# Expand integral formula with differential dx

Tags: definite-integrals

I read the following formula which expands the integral from [SICP](https://sarabander.github.io/sicp/html/1_002e3.xhtml#g_t1_002e3_002e1)

[image]

for small values of d x . We can express this directly as a procedure:

```
(define (integral f a b dx)
  (define (add-dx x) (+ x dx))
  (* (sum f (+ a (/ dx 2.0)) add-dx b) 
     dx))

(integral cube 0 1 0.01)
.24998750000000042

(integral cube 0 1 0.001)
.249999875000001
```

Nonetheless, I did not find the above expanded formula from [Integral on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral)

Is the formula a universal solution to decompose integral or singularly for particular functions.

Appreciate it very much if reference it origin or detailed illustration since I simply cannot get its idea.

Comment: Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum

Comment: wow, thank you very much, could you please transmit the link to answer.  @MaximilianJanisch